# strong completeness of a formal system

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, formal-proofs, hilbert-calculus

Given a formal system $D$ where the axioms are the same as in Hilbert system for propositional logic and the inference rule is $$\frac{a\rightarrow b, \quad a\rightarrow \neg b}{\neg a}$$ I need to answer:

1. Is the system sound (if $\vdash_D \varphi$ then $\models \varphi$)?
2. Is the system strongly sound (if $\Sigma\vdash_D \varphi$ then $\Sigma\models \varphi$ for every $\Sigma$ set of propositions)?
3. Is the system strongly complete (if $\models \varphi$ then $\vdash_D \varphi$)?

I managed to answer questions 1 & 2, but I can't find an answer for 3, neither prove strong completeness nor find a counterexample.

Comment: What do you mean by "sound", "strongly sound" and "strongly complete"?

Comment: 1. sound/soundness - if $\vdash \varphi$ then $\models \varphi$


2. strong soundness - if $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ then $\Sigma \models \varphi$ where $\Sigma$ is a set of propositions


3. strongly completeness - if $\models \varphi$ then $\vdash \varphi$

Comment: What are the axioms and the other inference rules in your Hilbert system?

Comment: there are no other inference rules, the axioms are the same as the Hilbert system i.e $$(\varphi\rightarrow (\psi\rightarrow\varphi))$$
$$(\varphi\rightarrow (\psi\rightarrow\theta))\rightarrow ((\varphi \rightarrow \psi ) \rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow\theta))$$
$$(\neg\psi\rightarrow\neg\varphi )\rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow\psi)$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the system $D$ is not strongly complete. Indeed, consider the formula $((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$ where $X$ and $Y$ are propositional variables.

It is immediate to verify that $\models ((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$ by means of a truth table: for every truth assignment to $X$ and $Y$, the formula $((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$ turns out to be true.

However $\not\vdash_D ((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$  for the following reason:

- the formula $((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$ is not an instance of any axiom of system $D$, and
- the formula $((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$ cannot be derived by applying the only inference rule in system $D$, because any conclusion of such a rule has the form $\lnot \varphi$, which is not the form of the formula $((X \to Y) \to X) \to X$.

---

The formal argument to answer question 3 is what I wrote above. Here I give an informal explanation, which contextualizes the answer.

Intuitively, the idea is that the only inference rule in system $D$ does not allow the number of $\lnot$ to decrease, when reading it top-down: if $\psi$ is a formula in one of the two premises in the only  inference rule of system $D$, and $\varphi$ is its conclusion, then the number of $\lnot$ occurring in $\varphi$ cannot be less than the number of $\lnot$ occurring in $\psi$.

Therefore, the fact that $ \vdash_D \lnot \lnot \varphi$ (i.e. $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ is provable in system $D$) does not imply that $\vdash_D \varphi$.
This fact could seem counterintuitive because $\varphi$ and $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ are logically equivalent, that is, they have the same truth table (formally, $\models \lnot \lnot \varphi$ if and only if $\models \varphi$).
Logical equivalence is a *semantic* notion, while provability $\vdash_D$ is a *syntactic* notion: the only means you have to conclude that $\vdash_D \varphi$ are the axioms and the only inference rule of system $D$. It does not matter if $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ is logically equivalent to $\varphi$, in system $D$ you do not have any rule that allows you to go from $\lnot\lnot \varphi$ to $\varphi$.

If system $D$ were *strongly complete* (and sound), then you could freely interchange $\models$ (semantic validity) with $\vdash_D$ (syntactic provability in system $D$), and so you could say that, since $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ is logically equivalent to $\varphi$, the fact that $\vdash_D \lnot \lnot \varphi$ (i.e. $\lnot\lnot \varphi$ is provable in system $D$) would imply that $\vdash_D \varphi$.
But in fact system $D$ is *not* strongly complete, and so $\models$ and $\vdash_D$ cannot be freely interchanged.

Comment: but what if $\vdash_D (\neg a \rightarrow b)$ and $\vdash_D (\neg a \rightarrow \neg b)$ then $\vdash_D a$? can you prove that there isn't proposition $b$ such that $\vdash_D (\neg ((( X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X) \rightarrow b)$ and $\vdash_D (\neg ((( X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X) \rightarrow \neg b)$ and therefore $\nvdash_D (( X \rightarrow Y) \rightarrow X) \rightarrow X$?

Comment: @CforLinux - In system $D$, from $\lnot a \to b$ and $\lnot a \to \lnot b$ you can only deduce $\lnot \lnot a$, which is different from $a$. And in system $D$ there is no rule to derive $a$ from $\lnot \lnot a$.

Comment: Not sure I understand, isn't $\neg\neg a\equiv a$? Therefore $a$ is proven?

Comment: @CforLinux - Yes, $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ and $\varphi$ are logically equivalent (i.e. $\models \lnot \lnot \varphi$ if and only if $\models \varphi$). Logical equivalence is a _semantic_ notion, while provability $\vdash_D$ is a _syntactic_ notion: the only means you have to conclude that $\vdash_D \varphi$ are the axioms and the inference rule of system $D$. It does not matter if $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ is logically equivalent to $\varphi$, in system $D$ you do not have any rule that allows you to go from $\lnot \lnot \varphi$ to $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

> $$ \frac{a\rightarrow b, \quad a\rightarrow \neg b}{\neg a}$$

This axiom doesn't prevent defining $\lnot X = \top$ .  So you won't be able to prove any theorem that distinguishes $\top$ from $\lnot$.  For example,

$$P \to \lnot P \to Q$$

holds under the intended meaning of $\lnot$, but $P \to \top \to Q$ is not going to be provable from sound axioms.

---

Another way of putting it is that any theorem provable from the given axioms will also be soundly true when any expression $\lnot X$ is replaced by $\top$ (true).  So any tautology, which is not a tautology after a replacement, will not be provable.

Comment: What is $\top$? There are no axioms for it. If you want to use $\top$ as a constant for "always true", you need to add some axioms and so the system won't be $D$ anymore.

Comment: $\top$ a semantic concept, it doesn't need axioms.